# total rms current from rms current values

Tags: signal-power, electrical-signal

I would like to calculate the RMS current value over a say an hour from RMS current values taken at minute intervals. I don't have access to the instantaneous current values, just the rms current value at minute intervals. How do I go about calculating this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best shot is simply

$$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} I_m^2[n]}$$

where $I_m[n]$ are the individual current readings.

Whether this is any good really depends on how much variation the underlying current has and how quickly it changes.

Comment: So ultimately, you are saying calculate the RMS value of individual RMS values to get the total?

Comment: yes. That feels like the best option